# Set previous user-agent to webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

1)I have integrated the `webView` & I m setting the `user-agent` with some string. When I load the `webView` first time it will set correctly but when I `Reload` it by setting different `user-agent` string it wont set. It just set previous `user-agent`. I tried clearing the cache it still not work.

2)I am calling this method from `ViewWillAppear`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];

      [self loadWebView];
   }
-(void)loadWebView
{
   NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some url"];
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:kTimeoutInterval]; 
   [request setValue:@"some String" forHTTPHeaderField:@"user-agent"];
   webView.delegate = self;
   [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to the people you are asking to help you with this question if you could state what you have tried, or show a code example and show us the results of your attempted reloading of the web view. If you need help please look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask thanks :)

Comment: Edited with code please check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long work-out I solved this issue as follows

- I observed that if you load any url in `webView` with a `user-agent`
  set to it. After some time you load the `different url` & `different user agent` but used the same allocated WebView instane.The web view will load the new url but can not set new user agent. It just set old one that you have set before loading first time.
- You can not change untill you initiate new instanse of `UIWebview`(or we can say that user agent can be set once per session).
- What I did for this problem is, I allocated new instance when I
  want set new `user agent`.